# AwK align longer columns to next line and keep same count of processed rows/lines

Tags: awk, count, multiple-columns, rows

Hi i have this problem with this type of input data:

input file which is contain those columns:

file1 (original file)

```
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04      
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
7 LINE_C G_PREFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04      
8 LINE_G G_PREFX D_VALUEFX POSITION55 POSITION82 VALUE85 POSITION44 POSITION448 POSITION448 POSITION448
7 LINE_C G_PREFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 

5 Lines processed
```

I tried to make it align long columns to next line which is resulting with help of following code of:

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 9) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2), $(i+3), $(i+4), $(i+5), $(i+6), $(i+7), $(i+8), $(i+9)}' file1
```

file1 (processed file)

```
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
7 LINE_C G_PREFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04
8 LINE_G G_PREFX D_VALUEFX POSITION55 POSITION82 VALUE85 POSITION44 POSITION448 POSITION448
POSITION448 
7 LINE_C G_PREFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03

7 Lines processed
```

@Goal is to make it output like this or even better based on your idea, but still to keep same number of processed lines

```
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
          EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
7 LINE_C G_PREFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04
8 LINE_G G_PREFX D_VALUEFX POSITION55 POSITION82 VALUE85 POSITION44 POSITION448 POSITION448
          POSITION448 
7 LINE_C G_PREFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03

5 Lines processed
```

for counting i am using this code below: but after shortening with AWK loop code, it resulting into NR of lines  7

```
awk '{print $0;NR;}END {print "\n" "\033[48;5;085;38;5;000m" NR, "Lines processed""\033[0m";}'
```

Thank you, for any ideas with this

Comment: Are you saying you want to wrap long lines at some number of characters or some number of fields and indent the wrapped lines? If so - what is that number and is it characters or fields? If not - clarify what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: why not do both in the same script, so that you don't lose count of the number of lines?  Also what is processing  other than wrapping text?

Comment: well i would like to wrap in fact long lines at some number of fields(i am using name here as columns) maybe its causing misunerstanding here, number is 9. , i would like to wrap longer lines and alingn them nicely to next line with keeping or returned count of processed lines (rows)

Comment: @karakfa ,well its okay its like that:`
awk '{print $0;NR;}END {print "\n" "\033[48;5;085;38;5;000m" NR, "Lines processed""\033[0m";}' file1 | awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 9) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2), $(i+3), $(i+4), $(i+5), $(i+6), $(i+7), $(i+8), $(i+9)}' ` but still missing wrapping it nicely somehow , as i am lost here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
$ cat file
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
7 LINE_C G_PREFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04
8 LINE_G G_PREFX D_VALUEFX POSITION55 POSITION82 VALUE85 POSITION44 POSITION448 POSITION448 POSITION448
7 LINE_C G_PREFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03

$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? (i%9 ? OFS : ORS "\t") : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
7 LINE_A G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04
7 LINE_B G_VALUEFA D_VALUEFA SEAT22 SEAT25 SEAT27 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8 EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
        EXNUM899999SSSSS9S8S5S2S8
7 LINE_C G_PREFX D_VALUEFX SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03 SEAT04
8 LINE_G G_PREFX D_VALUEFX POSITION55 POSITION82 VALUE85 POSITION44 POSITION448
        POSITION448 POSITION448
7 LINE_C G_PREFA D_VALUEFA SEAT01 SEAT02 SEAT03

$ awk -f tst.awk file | awk '!/^\t/{++c} END{print c+0, "Lines processed"}'
5 Lines processed
```

Obviously you could just print NR in the END of the first script if you wanted to print the "Lines processed" number there so I'm assuming you want to print it from some subsequent script though I can't imagine why.

Comment: you are right, thats what i searched for, just wrap and a bit move it with "\t",, i will adapt that, thank you, now i am a bit more clear with this processing , have a good day